# Is there any way to highlight a file with problems in the IntelliJ project view

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm writing a plugin that supports my DSL in Intellij and I'm facing the issue with highlighting files with problems in the project view.

I succesfully highlighted problems in code via `localInspection` extension and `InspectionManager.createProblemDescriptor` method but it affects nothing in the project view.

I didn't find the answer in the Intellij documentation for inspections: https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/code_inspections.html

Maybe I should create another problem descriptor for a file inside my localInspection?
Or I need another inspection for a file specifically?
Or may be there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If your inspection reports problems of Error severity, you can implement the `<problemFileHighlightFilter>` extension to enable the highlighting. Note that this will work only on files that the user opens in the editor; IntelliJ IDEA will not run inspections on all files in the project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please clarify one thing. `problemFileHighlightFilter` is just a `Condition` and takes `VirtualFile` as an argument so how can I get problems of Error severity associated with this file to decide whether I should highlight it or not? Maybe there is some helper class like `InspectionManager`?

Comment: The `Condition` simply tells that highlighting is supported for this type of files. The checks are done by the platform.